# CMake can't find libcurl in the sysroot

Tags: c, linux, cmake, libcurl, toolchain

I am new to using CMake. I am cross compiling using CMake on a Debian host for an device running embedded Linux. Below is my CMake toolchain file :

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)     # this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)     # this one not so much

# this is the location of the amd64 toolchain targeting the device 
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/bsp/bsp-linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc)

# this is the file system root of the target
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot)

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)


SET(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/lib)
SET(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR /home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/include/openssl)
```

I reach an error that CMake cannot find curl as follows :

```
Cross compiling not using pkg-config
-- Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  c-utility/CMakeLists.txt:522 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
```

libcurl is located in the sysroot for the target in the following folder :

```
/home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/lib/libcurl.so
```

Why doesn't CMake find this , and how can I tell CMake to find the library here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting the CURL root directory as you did with OpenSSL: `SET(CURL_ROOT_DIR ... )` ?

Comment: BTW, for the real **sysroot** there is special CMake variable: [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html). The directory set in this variable has the same properties as one listed in `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` variable, so `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*` settings affects on this directory too. Additionally, CMake automatically generates `--sysroot` option for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Either SET or pass CURL_LIBRARY and CURL_INCLUDE_DIR variables to your CMake invocation:

```
-DCURL_LIBRARY=/home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/lib/libcurl.so -DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/include/
```

Comment: Variable `CURL_LIBRARY` should refer to the library itself - `/home/bsp/bsp-linux/sysroot/usr/lib/libcurl.so`, - not to the *directory* with the library.